# Get Title and Description of external URL using Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how I can extract the `Title` and `Metadescription` of an external site using it's URL. I've found some solutions but not for django/python.

Currently my code adds a link to a database and I would like to make it go to the link after it is added and then update the entry with the corresponding `Title` and `Metadescription`.

It would also be nice to be able to retrieve the `og` tags such as `meta property="og:url`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the title or description of an external site you have to do two things.

1) You need to fetch the html external site.
2) You need to parse the html and get the title element and the meta elements.

The first part is easy:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
external_sites_html = opener.open(external_sites_url).read()
```

The second part is more difficult, as we need to use an external library to parse the html, I like a library called BeautifulSoup because it has a really nice api. (It is easy for programmers to use.)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(external_sites_html)
# Now we can get the tags of the external site from the soup variable.
title = soup.title.string
```

However, it is important to remember that the external site may only respond slowly when we fetch it, so it would probably be wise to make the external site record in your database, then return a reply to the user. Then in some other process, you should go and fetch the url and add the extra information to the database. If it's important that the extra information is returned in the reply, then you cannot do this in the background and will have to make your user wait.

Comment: I had to make some changes but it's working perfecly. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer helped you then it would be nice if you would accept it.

Comment: for info in pyhton 3.5, use: 
`from urllib.request import urlopen` and `external_sites_html = urlopen(external_sites_url).read()`

Comment: You'll also get a warning unless you do `soup = BeautifulSoup(external_sites_html, "html.parser")`

Answer (score 3):

I get [@ryan-pergent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41648695/1177566) answer and improved it, `metadata.py`:

```py
import re
import subprocess
from subprocess import TimeoutExpired
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class Metadata:
    url = ""
    type = "" # https://ogp.me/#types
    title = ""
    description = ""
    image = ""

    def __str__(self):
        return "{url: " + self.url + ", type: " + self.type + ", title: " + self.title + ", description: " + self.description + ", image: " + self.image + "}"

class Metadatareader:

    @staticmethod
    def get_metadata_from_url_in_text(text):
        # look for the first url in the text
        # and extract the url metadata
        urls_in_text = Metadatareader.get_urls_from_text(text)
        if len(urls_in_text) > 0:
            return Metadatareader.get_url_metadata(urls_in_text[0])
        return Metadata()

    @staticmethod
    def get_urls_from_text(text):
        # look for all urls in text
        # and convert it to an array of urls
        regex = r"(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?"
        return re.findall(regex, text)

    @staticmethod
    def get_url_metadata(url):
        # get final url after all redirections
        # then get html of the final url
        # fill the meta data with the info available
        url = Metadatareader.get_final_url(url)
        url_content = Metadatareader.get_url_content(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url_content, "html.parser")
        metadata = Metadata()

        metadata.url = url
        metadata.type = "website"

        for meta in soup.findAll("meta"):
            # priorize using Open Graph Protocol
            # https://ogp.me/
            metadata.type = Metadatareader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:type", metadata.type)
            metadata.title = Metadatareader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:title", metadata.title)
            metadata.description = Metadatareader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:description", metadata.description)
            metadata.image = Metadatareader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:image", metadata.image)
            if metadata.image:
                metadata.image = urljoin(url, metadata.image)

        if not metadata.title and soup.title:
            # use page title
            metadata.title = soup.title.text

        if not metadata.image:
            # use first img element
            images = soup.find_all('img')
            if len(images) > 0:
                metadata.image = urljoin(url, images[0].get('src'))

        if not metadata.description and soup.body:
            # use text from body
            for text in soup.body.find_all(string=True):
                if text.parent.name != 'script' and text.parent.name != 'style' and not isinstance(text, Comment):
                    metadata.description += text

        if metadata.description:
            # remove white spaces and break lines
            metadata.description = re.sub('\n|\r|\t', ' ', metadata.description)
            metadata.description = re.sub(' +', ' ', metadata.description)
            metadata.description = metadata.description.strip()

        return metadata

    @staticmethod
    def get_final_url(url, timeout=5):
        # get final url after all redirections
        # get http response header
        # look for the "Location: " header
        proc = subprocess.Popen([
                    "curl",
                    "-Ls",#follow redirect 301 and silently
                    "-I",#dont download html body
                    url
                ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        try:
            out, err = proc.communicate(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutExpired:
            proc.kill()
            out, err = proc.communicate()
        header = str(out).split("\\r\\n")
        for line in header:
            if line.startswith("Location: "):
                return line.replace("Location: ", "")
        return url

    @staticmethod
    def get_url_content(url, timeout=5):
        # get url html
        proc = subprocess.Popen([
                    "curl",
                    "-i",
                    "-k",#ignore ssl certificate requisite
                    "-L",#follow redirect 301
                    url
                ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        try:
            out, err = proc.communicate(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutExpired:
            proc.kill()
            out, err = proc.communicate()
        return out

    @staticmethod
    def get_meta_property(meta, property_name, default_value=""):
        if 'property' in meta.attrs and meta.attrs['property'] == property_name:
            return meta.attrs['content']
        return default_value
```

Here is how I use it:

```py
from metadatareader import Metadata, Metadatareader

content = "YOUR TEXT CONTAING URLS GOES HERE, LIKE google.com"
metadata = Metadatareader.get_metadata_from_url_in_text(content)
print(metadata)
```

Comment: This code evolved here https://github.com/vitorfs/bootcamp/blob/master/bootcamp/helpers.py#L121

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class MetaDataReader:

    @staticmethod
    def get_url_metadata(external_sites_url):
        external_sites_html = urlopen(external_sites_url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(external_sites_html, "html.parser")

        title = soup.title.text
        image = ""
        description = ""

        for meta in soup.findAll("meta"):
            title = MetaDataReader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:title", title)
            image = MetaDataReader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:image", image)
            description = MetaDataReader.get_meta_property(meta, "og:description", description)

        return {'title': title, 'image': image, 'description': description}

    @staticmethod
    def get_meta_property(meta, property_name, default_value=""):
        if 'property' in meta.attrs and meta.attrs['property'] == property_name:
            return meta.attrs['content']
        return default_value
```

Feel free to handle your own default values if there is no meta with og:title, og:description or og:image :)

More info about BeautifulSoup:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about extracting the title and meta tags from an external webpage? I'm a fan of mechanize and BeautifulSoup. An example of extracting the title is below.

```
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
def get_title(url):
    br = Browser()
    r = br.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    return soup.find("title").text
```

to get the meta tags, I would use something along the lines of

```
for meta in soup.findAll("meta"):
    print (meta['name'], meta['content'])
```

of course you probably want to do something other than print them.

Comment: Spawning a full fledge browser session for just making the HTTP request?

Comment: @sharjeel instantiating a mechanize.Browser is not expensive and gives you a whole lot for free, like handling redirects and presenting a decent agent string.